# Button inside UpdatePanel does not redirect me to another page

Tags: asp.net

I have a form with a button that validates a required field and then if the validation is ok send me to another page. I have used AJAX with UpdatePanel that shows me a label if the field is required or not.
The problem is that when I press the button and the validation is correct it does not redirect me to another page.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upn_Data" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
<ContentTemplate>
<div class="row inp-row check-field">
    <label for="option" class=" ">Option1 :*</label>
        <div class="text-inp with-tooltip">&nbsp;
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOption1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddlOption1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="lblRequiredOption1" runat="server" Text="Obligatory field" visible="false" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:Label> 
        </div>
</div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
<ContentTemplate>
    <div id = "buttons" class ="buttons">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text = "Continue" class="continue-btn" onclick="Button1_Click"></asp:Button>
    </div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In server:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool nextPage = true;

    if (ddlOption1.SelectedValue == "*")
    {
        lblRequiredOption1.Visible = true;
        nextPage = false;
    }

    if (nextPage == true) {
       Type cstype = this.GetType();
       String csName = "RedirectScript";
       String script = "window.parent.location = '../Paso2.html'";

       ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
       cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(cstype, csName, script.ToString(), true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is debugger able to reach `Button1_Click` event?

Comment: Or is the value of `nextPage` always false? If so find out why.

Comment: Yes, the debugger arrives at the Button1_click event. Also goes through the instruction cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock() but it does not change of page. If I remove the button inside UpdatePanel and I do not use Ajax then it Works. But I need to use ajax to validate

Comment: The value of nextPage is true when the validation is correct